# Find the probability distribution in ball pit question

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a ball pit with A balls that are white, B balls that are black. n balls are drawn randomly. What is the probability that k balls are white?

I feel like this is equivalent to a coin toss where p=A/(A+B) but I'm not quite sure.

Thanks

Comment: With or without replacement?

Comment: They are all taken together, if that makes sense

Comment: I understand, without replacement.

Comment: It´s just the application of the Hypergeometric distribution: $$P(X=k)=\frac{\binom{A}{k}\cdot \binom{B}{n-k}}{\binom{A+B}{n}}$$. This is not equal to $A/(A+B)$

Comment: Coin toss is a game with replacement.

Comment: The reason that drawing balls without replacement is not equivalent to a coin toss is that coin tosses are independent; the outcome of one flip does not effect the probability of the next flip.  But if you draw one white ball from an urn, then there is now one less white ball, and it is less likely that the next ball will also be white.  If there is a huge number of white balls in the urn it doesn't make much difference, though.